# Getting the current branch name when running code on gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab

I have a python project on gitlab. I am trying to access the current branch name using the code:

```
from pygit2 import Repository
branch = Repository(".").head.shorthand
```

When I run this locally it correctly returns my local branch. However when it runs on gitlab it is returning `HEAD`. Does anyone know how I can get the current branch name on gitlab.

Comment: If you mean in CI, there are env variables available, for example, CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME (https://gitlab.id-network.ru/help/ci/variables/README.md)

Comment: I mean in a python script I want to get the name of that local branch.

Comment: import os
os.environ.get('CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME')

Comment: Yes I see. Thank you!